# How to write correct wolfram expression?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha, wolfram-language

How to write something like this expression on WolframAlpha to get the correct answer? 

`Solve[Sort[IntegerDigits[2*x]] == Sort[IntegerDigits[3*x]], x]`

The first possible x value equals to 1782.

`2*1782 = 3564
3*1782 = 5364`

Which are the same after sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it is possible to know enough Mathematica language notation that this can be used to coax WolframAlpha into giving an answer. This

```
Select[Table[{x, Sort[IntegerDigits[2*x]],Sort[IntegerDigits[3*x]]}, {x,6000}], #[[2]]==#[[3]]&]
```

or this

```
Select[Table[x,{x,6000}],Sort[IntegerDigits[2*#]]==Sort[IntegerDigits[3*#]]&]
```

works